# Twilio Device.destroy() not releasing the device and event handlers

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

We are using Twilio in our application for voice communication.

When making voice call, we are setting up Twilio device as below. 
If call is not successful, we are retrying few more time calling below function again.

My question is doesn't destroy function delete the event handlers as well? And why do I see in log "[Device] Found existing Device; using new token but ignoring options" when I call setup after calling destroy?

```
function setupTwilio(token) {
    if (angular.isFunction(Twilio.Device.destroy)) {
        console.log('Destroying Twilio device');
        Twilio.Device.destroy(); // Destroy before setup incase we have already run this
    }

    startEventHandlers(); // add event handlers for Twilio events e.g. connect, disconnect

    trySetup = function () {
        var params = { debug: ( DEBUG ? true : false ) };
        if (DEBUG) {
            console.log('trying the twilio setup at ' + new Date());
            console.log(Twilio.Device.instance);
        }
        // Twilio will not hit the handlers specified in startEventHandlers until a successful setup has been created, so run try catch here
        try {
            Twilio.Device.setup(token, params);
        } catch (e) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                console.log('TwilioSetup uncaught error: ' + e);
            }
        }
    };

    if (angular.isDefined(token)) {
        trySetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Destroy will trigger the offline event handler. Try [setting up the device](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#setup) inside the offline event handler:

```
Twilio.Device.offline(function() {
        Twilio.Device.setup(token, params);
    });
```